# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver' with GeckoDriver and Python in MAC OS

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have created a test script to open a url in Eclipse using python and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1516, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120/PythonSeleniumProject/src/PythonSeleniumModule.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have read in stack overflow about related topics but none of them answers/solves my problem.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the error message: "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH."?

Comment: @KlausD. may I know which is the correct path? I have pasted the geckodriver executable file in /usr/local/bin and in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver folders

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` should be fine. Can you run it from the terminal by simply running `geckodriver` in any folder?

Comment: I have run geckodriver and it now works. Thank you @Kla

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'
.
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the **GeckoDriver** within the mentioned directory.

As per your code trials you have used:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

As you havn't mentioned the *absolute path* of the **GeckoDriver** explicitly, your program searches for the **GeckoDriver** within the *paths* mentioned within your underlying *Operating System* **PATH** variable and unable to locate.

### Solution

- As you are on *Mac OS X* download the latest **geckodriver-v0.23.0-macos.tar.gz** from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), store it anywhere within your system.
- In your program override the *paths* mentioned in your *Operating System* **PATH** variable through the argument **`executable_path`** as follows:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
  print("Firefox Browser Invoked")
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: How do we do it for Linux

Comment: @Tessaracter pretty much the same

Answer (score 1):

The solution above will not work on every machine depending on the absolute path you choose. Also, the absolute paths that are easy to access via any program, e.g. root folder, requires admin permissions.

There's a DriverManager module to every Selenium WebDriver that exists, and you can use it to install the WebDriver on a directory inside PATH variable automatically.

*It is important that you do the installing just once. Doing it again will cause errors, and I haven't found how to overcome them yet.*

First, install webdriver-manager on your Python environment with
`pip install webdriver-manager`
or `pip3` if you're using Python3.

Do this on your code and it will work fine:

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
except Exception:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Therefore it will install only once on the machine using the program.

*Note: This has some issues with OperaDriver.*