# Firefox Selenium in Termux

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, termux

I have ubuntu running in termux, I installed pycharm to create python code. The problem is I'm having  some error opening the webdriver.

I have the latest firefox (v59.0.2), Selenium geckodriver v.0.24.0 and using python 3.6.5

This is the the code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox('/root/Downloads/geckodriver')
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
   File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 80, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 309, in copytree
names = os.listdir(src)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Downloads/geckodriver'
```

and if I do this

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/root/Downloads/geckodriver')
```

Here is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Downloads/geckodriver': '/root/Downloads/geckodriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: What happen if you try absolute path? `executable_path='C:/path_to_root/root/Downloads/geckodriver`

Comment: I believe C drive is only for windows, I am using ubuntu in termux bud.

Comment: It's not important what is the drive, it was just an example.

Comment: Okay given that I dont really know this stuff,  how to do that? I mean I dont know what to replace with `path_to_root`. The only thing that I know is my file system starts with /root/

Answer (score 1):

As per your first code trial this error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Downloads/geckodriver'
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the **GeckoDriver** within the mentioned directory.

> You can find a detailed analysis on this error with in the discussion [FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver' with GeckoDriver and Python in MAC OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960368/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-geckodriver-geckodri/52966326#52966326)

As per your second code trial this error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the **GeckoDriver** within the mentioned directory.

> You can find a detailed analysis on this error with in the discussion [WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH even though it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947694/webdriverexception-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-even-though-it/49955135#49955135)

### Solution

Ideally you need to:

- Ensure that **GeckoDriver** is having *executable* permission for **non-root** users.
- Execute your `@Tests` as a **non-root** user.
- Use the following code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/non_root_user/Downloads/geckodriver')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: for bullet 1 and 3, I have termux which is a `virtualenv` so its only `root` user not unless there is a way for me to check for the **non-root** user, I checked the permission and its all _read and write_ , I also tried to put it in `/usr/local/bin` and the result is `unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4`  and for the bullet 2 I don't know that, I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the geckodriver files into your PATH.
Type
echo $PATH
to find your PATH