# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents\\chromedriver.exec' error using Selenium on MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn how to use selenium and python as well i am trying to follow this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc&ab_channel=TechWithTim

This is the code I have :

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents\chromedriver.exec"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

But this is what keeps coming up on the terminal ( I am using VS Code and am on mac)

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/Python Projects/Selenium Automation /Web Scraping (1)/web_scraping_attempt.py"
fuadhafiz@Fuads-iMac Web Scraping (1) % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/Python Projects/Selenium Automation /Web Scraping (1)/web_scraping_attempt.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1819, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents\\chromedriver.exec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/Python Projects/Selenium Automation /Web Scraping (1)/web_scraping_attempt.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Documents\chromedriver.exec' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

and in the "problems" section

Anomalous backslash in string: '\c'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.

This is were the chrome driver is saved :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. In [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) systems the extension for the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) binary isn't required. So effectively your code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed relevant discussions in:

- [FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver' with GeckoDriver and Python in MAC OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960368/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-geckodriver-geckodri/52966326#52966326)

Comment: @7UAD Checkout the updated code block and the reference discussion.

Comment: Hi there, I have tried your code and it comes up with this :

raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Documents\chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: @7UAD So the error of _...FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory..._ within this question is resolved now. For the next error feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry im new to this Stack overflow thing

Answer (score 0):

see error message you are using wrong file extension .exec instead of .exe

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents\\chromedriver.exec'
```

try this instead

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

I am also using mac so install chromedriver in default PATH saves so much trouble of adding path each time

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

now you can simply call

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```